# Can I read another applications memory?

Tags: android, pebble-watch

I'd like to know wether it is possible to read some data from a foreign application in Android (like reading runtastics pulse, distance, pace e.g.) and include it into my own application?

I'm not asking because I wanna do some bad stuff with it, I'd just like to know that for some interesting Pebble development tasks.

Comment: You might be able to do something with root access -- but not with any documented APIs. This violates fundamental security models.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use supported Pebble APIs/etc?

Comment: If you are running under the same userid as the other application (or are root) you can use the linux kernel *ptrace* functionality to access the other processes's memory.  However, simply having access to memory is a far cry from being able to find and interpret numeric data (especially when dealing with a virtual machine).  For textual data though (or numeric which fits a pattern), it's plausible enough to that from a security perspective you can't dismiss the possibility of someone else doing it to you.

Comment: Okay. I already thought that it wouldn't be that easy. So i guess what Teovald says is the only way to solve this: wait or ask for an SDK by the developers of the official app ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By design, you absolutely can not do this (It must violate almost all the security principles).
Furthermore, even if you find a hack to do this, it will get you kicked of the Play Store if it is detected.
For the different apps you want to integrate, check their dev websites in order to see if they have an API/SDK allowing you to read the data you want to manipulate.