# Is it possible to hijack another process' memory?

Tags: memory

If I'm writing an application that stores sensitive data in memory — say personally identifiable information — do I have to worry about the possibility that while the program is running, another program with administrative privileges may be able to read/overwrite RAM where that information is stored?

I think I recall something about modern OS kernels automatically protecting against a situation like this. But isn't it true that a malicious user with sufficient privileges could override that behavior?

I'm not referring to a specific OS in this question, but instead OSes in general. If it's possible to do this in some OSes and not in others, I want to know which ones and why (although I suspect the exploit will work on *any* modern OS that allows root privileges).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I read another applications memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388615/can-i-read-another-applications-memory)

Comment: Could it be an example of YES http://www.artmoney.ru ? (Windows)

Comment: @NoyGabay The Question you linked is addressed for Android.

Comment: Well, what OS are you referring to?

Comment: In Windows, yes. A common example is the software Cheat-O-Matic. Another one is ArtMoney.

Comment: @NoyGabay Not me -> the OP and This is a Good question to him :-)